# Datagridview adding tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

I am adding columns to a datagrid view using a variable

```
UserVGrid.Columns.Add(newline[1], newline[1]);
```

Which works fine, but I don't seem to be able to work out how to add a tooltip for when I hover over the column description.

I want some thing like

```
UserVGrid.newline[1].tooltip = "some text in here"
```

But this is not allowed, can any one tell me the right code for it?

regards

Aaron (DEvilWAH)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `ToolTipText`.  It is a property of the `DataGridViewColumn`.

This is one possible solution:

```
DataGridViewColumn newColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();
newColumn.Name = newline[1];
newColumn.HeaderText = newline[1];
newColumn.ToolTipText = "some text in here";

UserVGrid.Columns.Add(newColumn);
```

Alternatively, you can refer to the column after it has been added to set the `ToolTipText` property:

```
int newColIdx = UserVGrid.Columns.Add(newline[1], newline[1]);
UserVGrid.Columns[newColIdx].ToolTipText = "some text in here";
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, like the first method best ;) had to change new DataGridViewColumn(); to new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();. but thats a nice method to do it and set it up perfect for something else i need to do. cheers